# Retrieve the immediate previous row based on Timestamp in SSMS

Tags: sql-server, sql-timestamp

I need to retrieve a set of rows based on a filtering criteria on Timestamp, which is - Timestamps with Time > 06:OO AM
However, I also need the immediate previous record less than 06:00 AM to calculate event duration's correctly

**How can I retrieve the rows having Time > 6:00 AM AND the last row which is less than 6:00 AM?**

Sample: I have these rows in the database and i have to calculate Event Duration's. If I just filter on Timestamp > 6:00 AM, the second also gets filtered out which i need for further calculations

Actual:

1. Event1 | Resource1 | 2019-05-26 04:38:16.1156432
2. Event2 | Resource1 | 2019-05-26 05:51:23.2356984
3. Event3 | Resource1 | 2019-05-26 06:01:32.1033333
4. Event4 | Resource1 | 2019-05-26 06:03:12.3245614

Applying the 'greater than 6:00AM' AND 'Previous row < 06:00AM' criteria, the result should look like:

**1. Event2 | Resource1 | 2019-05-26 05:51:23.2356984**
2. Event3 | Resource1 | 2019-05-26 06:01:32.1033333
3. Event4 | Resource1 | 2019-05-26 06:03:12.3245614

Comment: Do you need only the immediate previous row, not all the three row ?

Comment: You haven't actually asked a question. What exactly are you asking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering we have very little to go on here, the best I can offer is Pseudo-SQL.

Anyway, seems like what you want is a CTE and `LEAD`:

```sql
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT {Your Columns},
           LEAD({Your Date & Time Column}) OVER (/*PARTITION BY {Some Column(s)}*/ ORDER BY {Your Date & Time Column} AS NextTime --Uncomment/Remove PARTITION BY Clause as needed
    FROM {Your TABLE} YT)
SELECT {Your Columns}
FROM CTE
WHERE NextTime >= '2019-05-26T06:00:00';
```

You'll need to replace the appropriate parts in the Braces (`{}`).

Comment: Jut one more thing to add -  the Lead operation would return a NULL for the last row. I  modified the WHERE clause as:

WHERE NextTime >= '2019-05-26T06:00:00'
OR
NextTime is NULL

to get all the rows

Comment: yes, `LEAD`/`LAG` will return `NULL` if the value is beyond the scope defined in the partition. You';ll need to use a *default* value if you don't want it to return `NULL`, as outlined in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lead-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).